# python: dataframe into dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to replicate bokeh bar chart with nested categories as presented here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

My staring point is the below dataframe

```
test__df =  pd.DataFrame(data= [['2019-01-01','A',1],
                                ['2019-01-01','B',2],
                                ['2019-01-01','C',3],
                                ['2019-01-02','A',4],
                                ['2019-01-02','B',5],
                                ['2019-01-02','C',6],
                                ['2019-01-03','A',7],
                                ['2019-01-03','B',8],
                                ['2019-01-03','C',9]],
                       columns =['Date','Category','Count'])
```

I want to transform the data into dictionary as presented below, but have difficulties with the conversion.

```
Category = ['A', 'B', 'C']

Data = {'Category' : Category,
        '2019-01-01'   : [1,2,3],
        '2019-01-02'   : [4,5,6],
        '2019-01-03'   : [7,8,9]}
```

I tried to use function **.to_dict** in different configurations (‘dict’, ‘list’,’series’,’split’,’records’,’index’) but  no one was giving me the desired output.

**My question:**

**How can be done the transformation from the dataframe into the dictionary?**

Maybe it is not optimal way of creating that type of dictionary for the chart when starting with the dataframe, so how can this be better handled in that case?

Comment: the result which you have added. Is it correct? or do want  '2019-01-01'   : [1,2,3],

Comment: corrected the desired output to the numbers which you pointed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the important bit from that example, which is that what you need to construct is a list of coordinates, which in this case is a list of *(year, category)* tuples, and a list of corresponding counts. These can be gotten with `df.groupby` in various ways, here is one:

```
In [26]: g = df.groupby(by=['Date', 'Category'])

In [27]: coords = list(g.groups.keys())

In [28]: counts = [float(g.get_group(x).Count) for x in coords]

In [29]: coords
Out[29]:
[('2019-01-01', 'A'),
 ('2019-01-01', 'B'),
 ('2019-01-01', 'C'),
 ('2019-01-02', 'A'),
 ('2019-01-02', 'B'),
 ('2019-01-02', 'C'),
 ('2019-01-03', 'A'),
 ('2019-01-03', 'B'),
 ('2019-01-03', 'C')]

In [30]: counts
Out[30]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

Then used with Bokeh with this code:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(coords=coords, counts=counts))

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*coords), plot_height=250, toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x='coords', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

Results in the following Bokeh plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` to form lists and then `.to_dict`. Update the categories afterwards:

```
# If using dict to plot, should ensure it's sorted properly.
#test_df = test_df.sort_values(['Date', 'Category'])

d = test_df.groupby('Date').Count.apply(list).to_dict()
d['Category'] = test_df.Category.unique().tolist()

d
#{'2019-01-01': [1, 2, 3],
# '2019-01-02': [4, 5, 6],
# '2019-01-03': [7, 8, 9],
# 'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
```

Though if what you need is a plot, then this is made very easy with `seaborn` without creating the dictionary. This is also safer in the case that dates miss some categories or the `DataFrame` is initially unsorted, as categories and dates will be paired properly. (I add the sort just to get consistent plotting order of Dates-Category)

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.factorplot(x='Date', y='Count', hue='Category', data=test_df, kind='bar')
```

[image]

```
sns.factorplot(x='Date', y='Count', hue='Category', 
               data=test_df.sample(n=6).sort_values(['Date', 'Category']), 
               kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Question is how to construct a Bokeh plot given the data.

Comment: @bigreddot well the question is an XY problem and the actual problem isn't clearly stated `My question: How can be done the transformation from the dataframe into the dictionary?` with the title `python: dataframe into dictionary`. Sure if `bokeh` is *required* then this might not be 100% useful, but regardless of whether you use `bokeh` or `seaborn` the bar charts get the same information across. I don't see anywhere that `bokeh` is a requirement, and honestly, the seaborn syntax and integration with `pandas` makes that a concise alternative.

Comment: The very first sentence: *I am trying to replicate bokeh bar chart with nested categories*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
new_df = test__df.groupby('Date')['Count'].apply(list)
new_dict = new_df.to_dict()
```